# Cannot Upload Files to existing bucket in s3 SDK PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Trying to upload files using the PHP SDK of s3. Uploading the file to the existing Bucket, pops up the error.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
// Set plain text headers
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
// Include the SDK
require_once '../sdk.class.php';
```

//*%*********************************************************%*/
// UPLOAD FILES TO S3

```
// Instantiate the AmazonS3 class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$s3->path_style = true;

$bucket = 'photossss1.abc.com';

$name = "picture.jpg" ;
$response = $s3->create_object($bucket, 'picture2.jpg', array(
    'fileUpload' => 'picture.jpg'
));

if($response->isOk()){
    echo " Done" ;
} else {
    //var_dump($response);
    echo "error: create_object error.";
}
```

What is the error in the above code..?

Debug:
print_r($response->body); 
=>

```
CFSimpleXML Object
(
    [Code] => PermanentRedirect
    [Message] => The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
    [RequestId] => DACD5C54BC4BD82
    [Bucket] => photossss1.abc.com
    [HostId] => QUBlZEZKh0Ujzk6UyGG7LjC0vMCWDlOPszTZru/+OpWidBH84VXor1 
    [Endpoint] => photossss1.abc.com.s3.amazonaws.com
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set region after class initialization

```
// Initialize the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$s3->set_region( AmazonS3::REGION_EU_W1 );
...
```

[Related page on SDK Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/set_region)

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of:

```
<?php
print_r($response->body);
```

This should give you a proper error message from S3.

Comment: **print_r($response->body);**

`CFSimpleXML Object
(
    [Code] => PermanentRedirect
    [Message] => The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
    [RequestId] => DACD5C54BC4BD82
    [Bucket] => photossss1.abc.com
    [HostId] => QUBlZEZKh0Ujzk6UyGG7LjC0vMCWDlOPszTZru/+OpWidBH84VXor1
    [Endpoint] => photossss1.abc.com.s3.amazonaws.com
)`

Comment: Are you pushing to a non-US-East endpoint? Have you tried explicitly setting the region? `AmazonS3::set_region()`.

Comment: I am pushing to Bucket created in region EU (Ireland).

Answer (score 0):

in `services/s3.class.php`; 
replace this part:

```
const REGION_US_E1 = 's3.amazonaws.com';
```

to:

```
const REGION_US_E1 = 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
```